# Linq - filter inner list

Tags: c#, linq, filter

I’m trying to filter a list based on this classes - The result should be a list with all the machines where there are sessions that match the search condition, but only those sessions.

```
class Machine {
    public string collectionName  { get; set; }
    public string machineName  { get; set; }
    public bool status { get; set; }
    public List<Session> sessionList { get; set; }
    }

 class Session {
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string userName { get; set; }
    public string computerName { get; set; }
    public IPAddress ipAddress { get; set; }
    }

    List<Machine> allMachineData;

    var auxfindResults = (from machine_item in allMachineData
                          from session_item in machine_item.sessionList
                          where (session_item.userId.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(searchTerm.ToUpperInvariant())
                              || session_item.userName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(searchTerm.ToUpperInvariant()))
                          select machine_item).ToList();
```

I get a list of all machines with sessions matching the condition, but i also get results that I don't want i.e. sessions that don't match the conditions.

If instead I try:

```
var auxfindResults = (from machine_item in allMachineData
                          from session_item in machine_item.sessionList
                          where (session_item.userId.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(searchTerm.ToUpperInvariant())
                              || session_item.userName.ToUpperInvariant().Contains(searchTerm.ToUpperInvariant()))
                          select session_item).ToList();
```

I get all the sessions matching the condition, but obviously i loose the "machine" part

I have a working solution using loops, but I don't like it. 
Is there any way of doing this using linq - I’m sure there is, but I can’t find it.

Any suggestions/pointers will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: show us the working loop code.

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28685263/linq-to-return-list-of-object-filtered-on-a-property-of-a-child-object-in-nested ?

Comment: @Leszek Repie here it goes: heavily edited to fit 
List<Machine> results = new List<Machine>(); 
foreach (Machine m in allMachinesData) {
foreach (Session s in machine.sessionList) {
if (s.userId.Contains(searchTerm) || s.userName.Contains(searchTerm)))
{if (!CheckMachineExistsInList()){
Machine nMachine = new Machine();nMachine.collectionName = m.collectionName;
...results.Add(nMachine);
}else{
int pos = GetMachinePositionIndex(m.machineName);
results[pos].sessionList.Add(s);
}}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also filter the sessions you include in your selection.

Using Linq method syntax:

```
searchTerm = searchTerm.ToLower();
var result = allMachineData
    .Where(m => m.sessionList.Any(s => s.userId.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) || s.userName.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm)))
    .Select(m => new Machine
    {
        collectionName = m.collectionName,
        machineName = m.machineName,
        status = m.status,
        sessionList = m.sessionList.Where(s => s.userId.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm) || s.userName.ToLower().Contains(searchTerm)).ToList(),
    }).ToList();
```